# How to display grid view with images?

Tags: android

I'm trying to display grid view of images.I have tried the following code but my application gets force close after running.Where i have gone wrong?
My code:

AndroidGridLayoutActivity:

```
public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GridView gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                private Context mcontext;
                public Integer[] mThumbids={R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10,R.drawable.img11,R.drawable.img12,R.drawable.img13,R.drawable.img14};
                public ImageAdapter(Context c)
                {
                                mcontext=c;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return mThumbids.length;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return mThumbids[position];
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                ImageView imageView=new ImageView(mcontext);
                                imageView.setImageResource(mThumbids[position]);
                                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70,70));
                                return imageView;
                }



}
```

main.xml:

```
<GridView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/grid_view"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="90dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

Comment: 07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infy/com.infy.AndroidGridLayoutActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: 07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at com.infy.AndroidGridLayoutActivity.onCreate(AndroidGridLayoutActivity.java:15)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: 07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-03 11:43:03.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2184):

Comment: the problem seems inside your `ImageAdapter` please see some tutorial on how to create an Adapter

Comment: your `getView()` implementation is wrong

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
GridView gv1;

GridViewAdapter madapter;


int arr[]={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
String arr1[]={"ashu","hello","yes","no"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


gv1=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

madapter=new GridViewAdapter();


gv1.setAdapter(madapter);





}
```

class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arr1.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    LayoutInflater infla=getLayoutInflater();

    View v=infla.inflate(R.layout.main1,null);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ImageView iv1=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    tv1.setText(arr1[position]);

    iv1.setBackgroundResource(arr[position]);



    return v;
}}
```

}

> activity_main.xml
>
> ```
> <GridView  
> android:id="@+id/gridView1"   android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:padding="10dp"
> android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
>
> android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
> android:numColumns="auto_fit"
> android:columnWidth="60dp"
> android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
>
> android:gravity="center"
> /> </RelativeLayout>       
> main1.xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent" >
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:text="TextView" /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: try this ...you can edit int arr[] in main activity..if you want only imageview then please comment string arr1[] and textview in GridViewAdapter class.

Comment: Hi wat does activity_main.xml and main1.xml contains?

Comment: @ ashu could u pls explain the code? what is the use of LayoutInflater?

Comment: Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. It is never used directly. Instead, use getLayoutInflater() or getSystemService(String) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on.  you can study this  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html  and if this answer is useful for you then please accept this as a answer